# How to highlight (differentiate) negative numbers in plots?

Tags: plotting

I want to clearly see negative values in 3D plots. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple alternative is

```
Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, ColorFunction -> (If[#3 > 0, Red, Green] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, BoxRatios -> 1,
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> None,
 MeshShading -> {Directive[Opacity[.7, Red]], Directive[Opacity[.7, Green]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: With two answers following this interpretation perhaps I am just being obtuse not to see it as obvious.  If the OP does not edit the question to clarify it differently perhaps you would consider editing it yourself to make this meaning more apparent?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, based on a question in the comments section of a previous question by the same OP, i think he needs something like this. If Saman  does not edit the question in the next few minutes with further clarification, I will do so.